# Functions For Processing Images And Creating Data

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to doing image classification when i am try to process image preprocessing some Error of my code problem . When i am starting to convert images of my Dataset into array they have not convert all images into array .Please Help me out for my problem.

```
def process_image(image):
    ret,bi_inv = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    #plt.imshow(bi_inv, 'gray')
    return bi_inv, image

def create_data(tdir_, type_, frm, to, t_data):
    colored_data=[]
    bi_inv_data=[]
    print('Working On '+t_data+' Data : '+type_ +'\n')
    rng = ["%05d" % x for x in range(frm, to+1)]
    for i in rng:
        dir_ =tdir_+type_+'/'+i+'.jpg'
        image = cv2.imread(dir_, 0)
        bi_inv, colored_img = process_image(image)
        colored_data.append(colored_img)
        bi_inv_data.append(bi_inv)   
        
    print('Images Processed from '+rng[0]+' to '+rng[len(rng)-1]+'\n')    
    return colored_data, bi_inv_data
```

```
train_data_colr= []
train_labels=[]
train_data_inv = []

train_data_colr_pos, train_data_inv_pos=  create_data(train_dir, 'Cracks', 1, 1200, 'Training')

for i in range(0, len(train_data_colr_pos)):
    train_data_colr.append(train_data_colr_pos[i])
    train_data_inv.append(train_data_inv_pos[i])
    train_labels.append(1)

train_data_colr_neg, train_data_inv_neg=  create_data(train_dir, 'Normal', 1, 1200, 'Training')

for i in range(0, len(train_data_colr_neg)):
    train_data_colr.append(train_data_colr_neg[i])
    train_data_inv.append(train_data_inv_neg[i])
    train_labels.append(0)

train_data_colr_neg, train_data_inv_neg=  create_data(train_dir, 'Pothole', 1, 1200, 'Training')

for i in range(0, len(train_data_colr_neg)):
    train_data_colr.append(train_data_colr_neg[i])
    train_data_inv.append(train_data_inv_neg[i])
    train_labels.append(0)
    


final_train_colr = np.array(train_data_colr).reshape(((len(train_data_colr), 227, 227, 1 )))        
final_train_inv = np.array(train_data_inv).reshape(((len(train_data_inv), 227, 227, 1 )))   

print('Shape of Training Data : '+str(final_train_colr.shape))
```

#Error# 
###Working On Training Data : Cracks

Images Processed from 00001 to 01200

Working On Training Data : Normal

Images Processed from 00001 to 01200

Working On Training Data : Pothole

Images Processed from 00001 to 01200

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c00bf9411daf> in <module>()
     26 
     27 
---> 28 final_train_colr = np.array(train_data_colr).reshape(((len(train_data_colr), 227, 227, 1 )))
     29 final_train_inv = np.array(train_data_inv).reshape(((len(train_data_inv), 227, 227, 1 )))
     30 

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3600 into shape (3600,227,227,1)
###
```

Comment: Why not to add `opencv-python` tag to your post?

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion i am already add Opencv-python but it is not work.

Comment: I mean tag, not library :)